# Fresh Magento 2 install admin does not give login box

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, login, installation, styles

I'm fairly new to Magento 2 and have been attempting to add a copy on my local machine (operating system: Windows 10) so that I can try out some database migration tests.

I have installed XAMPP and proceeded with the installation instructions. I was then rewarded with the following screen:

[image]

The actual site address seems to open a follows:

[image]

However when I click on "Launch Magento Admin" I get taken to a blank screen:

[image]

I've opened the developers console to see if anything is wrong and the following errors seem to be in effect:

[image]

Looking at this, I would think that this is an effect of the adminhtml styles not being loaded.

Regardless, does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This is the problem with windows. Windows uses "\" as separator, the array "directories" contains entries with "/" as separator, so the check will always fail.

So you need to fix this by replacing the separator in core file:

```
Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator
```

function isPathInDirectories replace below code in isPathInDirectories function

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Comment: This is a quick fix and may be Magento will provide a patch to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi. Thanks @SaurabhDwivedi but I'm afraid that this hasn't resolved the issue. I'm still receiving the errors.

Comment: Run command : php bin/magento setup:upgrade  and then php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
Also can you send new error report again.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thank you very much!